# Nginx https redirects - stop further rules processing

Tags: https, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to configure http and https redirects from an old site to a new one.

According to the rewrite directive docs:

> If the replacement string begins with http:// then the client will 
>   be redirected, and any further rewrite directives are terminated.

And I'm trying to achieve the same with https to no avail. 
This is my server config:

```
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name mydomain.com

rewrite ^/path/resource(.*)$ $scheme://newdomain.com/newpath/resource$1 permanent;
...
return 301 http://newdomain.com/newpath/;
```

Using http I get what I'm looking for: if I access *mydomain.com/path/resource* I'm redirected to *newdomain.com/newpath/resource*.

However, the same with https redirects me to http://newdomain.com/newpath/.

I have **rewrite_log on** and in both cases the rewrite rule is matched but the https protocol does not stop further rules processing.

I have the feeling that either I'm missing something really obvious or I'm not approaching this problem properly. I wouldn't mind doing this in any different way at all if it works.

Have any of you out there any idea on how to achieve the http redirect with https too?

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to use `return` instead of `rewrite` for redirects, try matching the path with a location block

```
location ~ /path/resource(.*) {
    return 301 $scheme://newdomain.com/newpath/resource$1;
}
```

I think this way you know for sure there will be no further processing, because it's only 1 line, try it and tell me how it goes.

PS: This will maintain the `$scheme` of the request, requests to `http://` will be redirected to a `http://` and `https://` will be redirected to `https://`

Comment: I've tried this and I always get redirected to http no matter if the original url is http or https.

Comment: can you write the new config that you used ?

Comment: `server {  
  listen 80;  
  listen 443 ssl;  
  ssl_certificate ...crt_file;  
  ssl_certificate_key ...key_file;  
  server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;  
  root ...;  
  location ~ /path/resource.php(.*) {  
    return 301 $scheme://newdomain.com/newpath/resource$1;  
  }`

Comment: I don't know about this, but i usually create 2 different servers, one for ssl and one without.

Comment: I tried without the listen 80; line with the same behaviour. After a short conversation with a work mate, I'm starting to wonder if secure 301 redirects from a domain with a certificate to another domain with another certificate are possible at all.